# Edit Sound file in android

Tags: android, audio, editing

I need to edit a wave file(adjust the pitch,bass,etc) in android.How I can I achieve this?
I had been searching for this in the net,but couldnt find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,the files can be played with effect using the default Equalizer in android http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html